# Moving and reading a SMS Android C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, sms

I'm currently developing an application for Android with Xamarin and Visual Studio, so I program in C #. My application must be able to receive SMS and a phone number, move the Database mmssms.db to store it in a temp file for example. For about a month of research I found code is but the problem is that I always receive an error message that is "Cannot cast from source type to destination type" regardless of the phone number. So I think it is a problem to redirect SMS but I'm not sure I know how do you solve it you could help me please to solve this problem.

Thank you beforehand.

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Telephony;
using Environment = System.Environment;

namespace essai_receiver
{
    [Activity(Label = "essai_receiver", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            SMSReceiver sampleClass1 = new SMSReceiver();
            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        }
    }
}
```

SMSReceiver.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Telephony;
using Environment = System.Environment;

namespace essai_receiver
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "SMS Receiver", Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]

    public class SMSReceiver : Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public static readonly string INTENT_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            InvokeAbortBroadcast();
            try
            {
                if (intent.Action != INTENT_ACTION) return;

                var bundle = intent.Extras;

                if (bundle == null) return;

                var pdus = bundle.Get("pdus");
                var castedPdus = JNIEnv.GetArray<Java.Lang.Object>(pdus.Handle);

                var msgs = new SmsMessage[castedPdus.Length];

                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                String sender = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++)
                {
                    var bytes = new byte[JNIEnv.GetArrayLength(castedPdus[i].Handle)];
                    JNIEnv.CopyArray(castedPdus[i].Handle, bytes);

                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu(bytes);
                    if (sender == null) sender = msgs[i].OriginatingAddress;
                    sb.Append(string.Format("SMS From: {0}{1}Body: {2}{1}", msgs[i].OriginatingAddress,
                                            Environment.NewLine, msgs[i].MessageBody));
                }

                if (sender != null && sender.EndsWith("9135XXXXXX"))
                {    
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "IsOrderedBroadcast :" + IsOrderedBroadcast.ToString() + "\n" + sb.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    ClearAbortBroadcast();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndoidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="essai_receiver.essai_receiver" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk />
    <application android:label="essai receiver" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: What I want is that my application moves from 9135XXXXXX SMS number to register it on a ".txt" file or ".temp" for example, but the problem is that I can not do this . Could you help me please.

Comment: Firstly, you haven't answered my question, so I can't really help you fix your current issue. Secondly, your code doesn't show any kind of File access, so I don't know what problems you're having there. Thirdly, if your app runs on KitKat or above, you can't abort that broadcast, so it is going to appear in the default SMS app.

Comment: If I can not delete this post there are no error in my code but just that it is incomplete to access the files. In this case you could help me complete the please.

thank you beforehand

Comment: Where are you getting the `Cannot cast from source type to destination type` error?

Comment: @MikeM. is trying to help you.  You say you are getting an error "Cannot cast from source type to destination type" but cannot tell us which specific line it is occurring on.  We can't help you if you refuse to answer basic questions about your code.

Comment: I do not really know what line this error occurs. The application compiles and installs without problem, but when I get an SMS on my phone if I receive the message as a Toast. I'm sorry I forgot you press that my application compiles and installs without problem.

Comment: You get your message as a Toast because in your code you catch all the exceptions and show them as a Toast (see last lines of the code you posted). Your error is exception caused by some problem with your code. You must run your application with debugger and see where exactly in your code the exception is thrown. Or at the very least, change your code to Toast.MakeText(context, ex.StackTrace, ToastLength.Long).Show(). But debugger is better, of course.